# What happens in each scenario and how is this accomplished?

Tags: c++

I have a `Stack` **class** defined. Now, I want to reverse the stack by passing it to a `reverseStack` function. I want to know what happens in various scenarios. And finally, what is the best way to do it.

**STACK IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
class Stack {
        public:
            Stack() {
                a = new int[25];
                capacity = 25;
            }
            Stack(int size) {
                a = new int[size];
                capacity = size;
            }
            ~Stack() {
                delete[] a;
            }
            void push(int x) {
                if (index == capacity - 1) {
                    cout << "\n\nThe stack is full. Couldn't insert " << x << "\n\n";
                    return;
                }
                a[++index] = x;
            }
            int pop() {
                if (index == -1) {
                    cout << "\n\nNo elements to pop\n\n";
                    return -1;
                }
                return a[index--];
            }

            int top();
            bool isEmpty();
            void flush();

        private:
            int capacity ;
            int* a;
            int index = -1; // Index of the top most element
    };
```

---

**SCENARIO-1:**

```
void reverseStack(Stack& s) {
    Stack s2;
    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s.pop());
    }
    s = s2;
}

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    reverseStack(s);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**SCENARIO-2:**

```
Stack reverseStack(Stack& s) {
    Stack s2;
    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s.pop());
    }
    return s2;
}

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s = reverseStack(s);
    return 0;
}
```

---

In Scenario-1 (which fails), what does `s = s2` inside the function mean? I think it's a member-wise copy. Would it have worked if the data members didn't involve a pointer (`int* a`)?

Scenario-2 fails as well for the same reason. How do I accomplish what I'm trying to?

Should I have a copy-constructor (and how do I implement it?). How about overloading the assignment operator (again, how do I implement?) ?

I tried to implement it this way:

```
Stack Stack::operator = (Stack s) {
    capacity = s.capacity;
    int* a = new int[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        a[i] = s.a[i];
    }
    index = s.index;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Edited to define the constructors for a better understanding.

Comment: replace `int* a;` with `std::vector<int> a;`. Problem solved.

Comment: Oh, man, I was just about to mention that I can't use vectors. Why? Because this is a trick question.

Comment: If you've got vectors available you can use them 'til you get the code working. Then replace them.

Comment: The root issue is that copying a pointer doesn't copy what the pointer points to. `s = s2` is a copy assignment, which will be generated automatically by the compiler. You'll need to define your own copy assignment operator in the class to make sure that the elements of `a` are copied as well. Please make sure to make it clear when something is homework and what constraints you have.

Comment: Well, it's not really a homework. I just wanted to challenge myself by not using vectors and only using arrays. Also, I have just edited to add my implementation at the very end. Please check if it's correct.

Comment: Also, I've been dying to find a link on copy assignment. I can only find copy constructors and assignment operators but not copy assignment. Kindly help.

Comment: The first question I have is, do you want the reverse to be in-place or do you want to return a new stack that is reversed? A common way to reverse an array in-place is by swapping the first element with the last, second element with the second last, etc.

Comment: Is in-place reversal even possible?

Comment: Well, it fails even after I overloaded the assignment operator to handle the pointer data member. :(

Answer (score 1):

About the scenarios, the best one is the second because of the [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), i.e: The compiler will probably optimize away the copy of the return value and prevent an unnecessary copy.

Now, you are using **dynamic memory** in your class, which means the default implementation of the **copy constructor** and **assignment operator** will **not work** for you.

Copy constructor, it's almost the same as the assignment operator you write

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack& s)
 : capacity(s.capacity)
 , a(new int[capacity])
 , index(s.index)
{ // std::copy is just a shortcut, what you're doing is fine too
    std::copy(s.a, s.a + capacity, a);
}
```

The assignment operator you wrote is wrong in two ways:

1. It should return a `Stack` object by reference
2. The parameter should be a `const reference`

The rest is just ok

```
Stack& Stack::operator = (const Stack& s) {
    capacity = s.capacity;
    a = new int[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) { // or std::copy
        a[i] = s.a[i];
    }
    index = s.index;
    return *this;
}
```

**Update**

Tentative implementation of the `reverseStack` function (without side-effects), assuming index contains the actual number of items in the stack

```
Stack reverseStack(const Stack& s) {
    Stack s2(s.capacity);
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.index; ++i) {
        s2.a[i] = s2.a[s2.index -i];
    }
    return s2;
}
```

**Update** Thanks to `user657267` from pointing out `int* a = new int[capacity];` was wrong

Comment: Hmmm...two questions buddy. 1.Why do we need to write our own copy constructor as well? 2. Why do we need to return the Stack by reference?

Comment: 1. because of shared memory, the default implementation will copy the pointer, not its content. 2. that's how assignment operator works

Comment: Should probably `delete[] a` before assigning it to avoid a memory leak if the destination already had items in it.

Comment: @B-Mac More info about the assignment operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: PS: The function runs fine now, but it doesn't print the reversed stack...it just prints the original stack mate. :(

Comment: Some people keep mentioning the rule of three.What is the third one in the rule of three besides Copy Constructor and the Overloaded Assignment Operator? I know the name, but what does it do?

Comment: maybe you can post the implementation of `pop()`? It seems that the `reverseStack()` function may have side effects

Comment: @B-Mac Rule of three: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

Comment: @ichramm: Done buddy. Please check. :)

Comment: Thanks. This confirms my previous guess,  `reverseStack` affects the stack being reversed... Take a look to my proposal, it might help to improve that implementation.